# mysql wordpress php syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I get this error in my php error logs regarding one of my sites. I actually have another site with exactly the same setup but no errors....

I'm really lost on this one

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT *  FROM  wp_cat_banners where cat_id= made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/telegraph-wp-3-1/single.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/telegraph-wp-3-1/header.php')
```

This is my code....

```
<?
global $wpdb;
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
if($cat_ID!="")
{
$parent_id=get_top_parent_category((int) $cat_ID);
}
$sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM  wp_cat_banners where cat_id=$parent_id";
$cc=$wpdb->get_row($sql2, 'ARRAY_A');
$background=$cc['Background_image'];
if($background !="")
{
?>


<?
global $wpdb;
if(is_front_page() || is_page())
{
$sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM  wp_cat_banners_home where Id=1";
$cc=$wpdb->get_row($sql2, 'ARRAY_A');
$right_banner5=$cc['Right_banner5'];
if($right_banner5!="")
{
?>
<div id="bannerHead1"><?php echo $right_banner5; ?></div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
if(is_single())
{
$categories= get_the_category(); 
$cat_ID=$categories[0]->cat_ID;
}
else
{
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
}
if($cat_ID!="")
{
$parent_id=get_top_parent_category((int) $cat_ID);
$sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM  wp_cat_banners where cat_id=$parent_id";
$cc=$wpdb->get_row($sql2, 'ARRAY_A');
$right_banner5=$cc['Right_banner5'];
if($right_banner5!="")
{
?>
```

Comment: Your problem is that `$parent_id` is something that converts to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`$parent_id` is empty. You can fix this by:

```
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
if($cat_ID!="")
{
    $parent_id=get_top_parent_category((int) $cat_ID);
    $sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM  wp_cat_banners where cat_id=$parent_id";
}
else { //else code here }
```

This makes sure that `$parent_id` is set before calling the query. What you had, the query would run regardless if `$parent_id` is declared and set; thus the error.